# Проблемы с кодировкой кириллицы при использовании Savon для SOAP веб-сервиса

Tags: ruby, soap, ruby-on-rails

Нужно получить информацию с веб-сервиса. Использую гем Savon, работаю под Win7.

```
require 'rails'
require 'savon'

client = Savon.client(wsdl: "stockquote.wsdl")

operation = :get_catalog_items
message_3 = { cat_id: 1, eo_id: operation_3_code }

response = client.call(operation, message: message_3)
```

На самом деле код выше значения не имеет.

Веб-сервис отдаёт xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Дальше при обработке средствами Savon начинается мне непонятное.

```
puts response # => голый xml одной строкой, кириллица в виде знаков вопроса.

puts response.doc # => красивый nokogiri xml, кириллица в непонятной кодировке.

puts response.body # => парсинг xml в хэш с помощью nori (по умолчанию тоже использующего nokogiri), кириллица в правильной кодировке.
```

А хочу я получить красивый xml в нормальной кодировке. Попробовал поэкспериментировать с разными кодировками и методом encode, но меня ждала неудача (до кодировок дело и не дошло)

```
puts response.doc.encode('UTF-8','Windows-1251') # => in `<main>': undefined method `encode' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x361db50> (NoMethodError)

puts response.encode('UTF-8','Windows-1251') # => in `<main>': undefined method `encode' for #<Savon::Response:0x3692238> (NoMethodError)

@response = client.call(operation, message: message_3)
puts @response.encode # => in `<main>': undefined method `encode' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

На этом решил остановиться и спросить:
1) почему метод encode не работает?
2) как всё-таки перекодировать получаемый xml?

Comment: попробуй при инициализации Savon клиента выставить кодировку: client = Savon.client(wsdl: "stockquote.wsdl", encoding: 'Windows-1251')

Comment: Вы попробуйте сначала сохранить полученные данные с помощью `.encode`, а уж потом вызывать `puts` их из БД через переменную